# Create a foreign key using belongs_to between two mongoid collections

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid

There are two classes.

First class

```
class Baby
include Mongoid::Document

  field :first_name, type: String
  field :surname, type: String
  field :dob, type: Integer
  belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: :username
  validates :parent, :presence => true

end
```

Second class

```
class Parent
include Mongoid::Document

  field :username, type: String
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :surname, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :password, type: String
  has_many :baby

end
```

When I create a new instance of the `Baby` class, I pass in a `username`. This should correlate to a `username` in the `Parent` document. Effectively storing a relation between the `Baby` and the `Parent`.

```
Baby.create!(first_name: 'James', surname: 'Barr', dob: '17-09-2012', username: 'foo123')
```

I keep getting this every time:

```
Mongoid::Errors::Validations: 
message:
  Validation of Baby failed.
summary:
  The following errors were found: Parent can't be blank, Parent can't be blank
resolution:
  Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
```

Comment: The reason it is not setting the parent is because it tries to search `Parent.find('foo123')` i.e. it assumes the `username` value to match the id of a `Parent` record.